# Serialization error with Elasticsearch NEST/C#

Tags: nest

I'm using NEST to index my objects and I'm running into a Newtonsoft error on serialization. One of my objects has a self referencing loop. Would there be a way for me to access the JsonSerializer and change how it handles self-references without having to modify the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register custom converters on your client:

```
public void AddConverter(JsonConverter converter)
{
    this.IndexSerializationSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
    this.SerializationSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
}
```

This might be of help.

There is no direct way to alter the `JsonSerializerSettings` used in the client though.

Comment: If I fork the project and make the JsonSerializerSettings a property with a public getter, would you pull it?

Comment: I will, I might look at exposing the Json stuff in a more uniform matter so that other serializers could be used but for now that will scratch an itch so i'll pull :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a new api now, take a look at:

```
    var cs2 = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(settings => settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)
        .EnableTrace();
```

Thanks for adding the support!