# ElasticSearch NEST adds $type in the serialized request in MVC app

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to use NEST from MVC app, however I'm getting the request serialized incorrectly:

```
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : NEST POST http://localhost:9200/_search (00:00:00.8188240):
StatusCode: 400, 
    Method: POST, 
    Url: http://localhost:9200/_search, 
    Request: {
  "$type": "Nest.SearchDescriptor`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], Nest",
  "aggs": {
    "Period": {
      "$type": "Nest.AggregationDescriptor`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], Nest",
      "date_histogram": {
        "$type": "Nest.DateHistogramAggregationDescriptor`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], Nest",
        "field": "Timestamp",
        "interval": "day",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query is very simple:

```
        var cs2 = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).EnableTrace();
        var client = new ElasticClient(cs2);

        var res3 = client.Search<object>(q =>q.Aggregations(agg =>
                agg.DateHistogram("DayAgg", t => t.Field("Timestamp").Interval("day"))));
```

The exact same code works fine in console application, so I'm thinking that could be related to the serialization, since in the bad case the "$type" property is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found related issue: [Serialization error with Elasticsearch NEST/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593378/serialization-error-with-elasticsearch-nest-c)

The rootcause is following settings:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
```

And now there is a new api supported for settings: SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier

```
        var cs2 = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
            .SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(settings => settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)
            .EnableTrace();
```

Comment: Be aware that JSON.NET defaults can be altered globally: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data . I think something in your stack alters these to always include the CLR typename (something NEST does NOT do).